# MS-PST: What is the relationship between nodes, subnodes, and blocks?

Tags: language-agnostic, file-format, pst

I am having problems understanding some of the [Microsoft PST file format specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff385210%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

**My understanding:**

In the NDB layer, our entry is a NID.  Given a NID, we can find the leaf node in the BTree.  From there, we have bidData and bidSub.

bidData either points to an external data node, or a data tree.

bidSub points to a subnode tree.

**My questions:**

1. Can we have a subnode tree without a data tree?
2. What circumstances would we have a subnode tree?
3. Is the result of the subnode tree to be concatenated with the result of the data tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 5 questions.

1. What is the relationship between nodes, subnodes, and blocks?
2. Can we have a subnode tree without a data tree?
3. What circumstances would we have a subnode tree?
4. Is the result of the subnode tree to be concatenated with the result of the data tree?
5. Should I iterate through the data blocks/tree first, then the subnode tree, or is there some other way to organize the data I read ?

The answer to question 1 per the standard located [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff387097) is

> A node is an abstraction that consists of a stream of bytes and a
>   collection of subnodes. It is implemented by the NDB layer as a data
>   block (section 2.2.2.8.3.1) and a subnode BTree (section 2.2.2.8.3.3).
>   The NBTENTRY structures in the Node BTree (section 2.2.2.7.7.4) exist
>   to define which blocks combine to form nodes.

As per the diagram [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff386824), you see that a node has the NID, bidData and bidSub as per your understanding.

A summary is a node made up of a data block or a data BTree which can point to data blocks and subnode BTree.

A subnode BTree contains  SIBLOCK and SLBLOCK structures, which contain SIENTRY and SLENTRY structures.

Answering Question 2, Yes you can have a subnode Btree without a data BTree. Because a data tree is only one form of specifying bidData, the other is to specify the data block directory.

More specifically, in order to create a subnode as per [2.6.1.2.2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff386031), you are required to have a data block in order to associate the SLENTRY with it. This data block can be directly specified or can be datatree containing one or more external or internal data block references.

If your question is can we have a subnode Btree e.g. bidSub, without the relevant bidData being set, the answer is no as per above. If you have bidData initialised to 0x0 as per [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6937870e-ea6a-4fc1-a1d9-049fa54b758b/what-version-of-spec-mspst-outlook-20072010-really-conforms-to?forum=os_exchangeprotocols) for representing a placeholder Node that doesn't yet have a datablock, the SLENTRY's won't be associated with the placeholder Node, until a valid bidData is set.

Answering Question 3, Subnodes are used to divide data in to logical / hierarchical sections. I don't know your circumstances , so I can't really answer this question beyond the following answer.

You would have subnode trees, when you are needing to store data in PSTs that leads itself well to logical separation. Examples of existing use of subnodes are in Message object as per [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff385158) to store attachments in the Messaging Layer , and in storing Table Contexts in the LTP layer as per [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff386198) and for additional storage in Property Contexts as per [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff385420).

Answering Question 4, I don't understand what you mean by the term result. As far as I know combination of information from data trees and subnode trees happens at the LTP or Messaging Layers.

Answering Question 5, it really depends what you are doing ? The PST SDK provides a mechanism to iterate over nodes in a node database, a mechanism to read from the node a stream, rather than directly, it also provides a method to iterate over the the first level of subnodes as per [here](http://pstsdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ndb) and [here](http://pstsdk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#fairport/trunk/pstsdk/ndb/node.h).

**References (other than already linked)**

- [NDB Layer Overview](http://pstsdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ndb)
- [Understanding the Outlook MS-PST Binary File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615595)
- [PST SDK documentation](http://pstsdk.codeplex.com/documentation)

Comment: Perhaps one of my assumptions is incorrect.  I see the NDB layer as providing an interface to the LTP layer where the LTP layer can ask for a NodeID, and the NDB layer returns a single Stream, which will iterate through all the data associated with that NodeID.

Comment: Given that assumption, question 4 asks: Should I iterate through the data blocks/tree first, then the subnode tree, or is there some other way to organize the data I read

Comment: As per your response for question 3, it leads me to believe that subnodes are not relevant at the NDB layer, and the NDB layer should possibly expose a second stream for the subnode tree?

Comment: I guess I'm still not understanding why someone would use a subnode tree?  I know that (Unicode) a data block has a maximum data size of 8176 bytes (8192 minus BLOCKTRAILER), an XBLOCK can reference 1021 data blocks, yielding 7.96 MB, and an XXBLOCK can reference 1021 XBLOCKs, yielding 7.93 GB.  Is a subnode tree used when I need to store data larger than 7.93 GB?  Or, is it used for specific circumstances, such as the message is stored in a data tree, attachments in a subnode tree, or another specific circumstance?

Comment: The later. Subnode trees are used for conceptual / logical separation of data as per the answer I gave and the examples. People normally don't make objects at the NDB level directly instead they make objects at LTP and PST levels which use heaps on Nodes and BTrees on Heaps on Nodes as per [here](http://pstsdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ltp)

Comment: So then would I expose two separate streams to the LTP layer, one for the Data tree, and one for the subnode tree?

Comment: The streams are per node or subnode and not for the whole tree when using the direct NDB layer constructs.

Comment: I may be beginning to understand.  I should yield a Node object (or some other construct).  This Node object would expose a stream (iterating through data blocks), and a tree of Nodes representing the subnodes.  At the LTP layer, objects will utilize the subnodes.

Comment: in summary... 2.) Yes, we can have subnode tree without data tree.  They are independent. 3.) The choice to have a subnode tree is made by higher layers. 4.) Subnode tree has nothing to do with data tree 5.) Expose the data blocks (as a stream, if possible), and also a BTree for the subnodes.  ;;  Is this correct?

Comment: Your summary isn't correct but it isn't incorrect either.  1. Being specific and using the general definition of data tree (where data tree isn't a data BTree) from standard  as A data tree collectively refers to all the elements that are used to store data, you need either a datablock or a datatree in order to have a subnode tree.  3. The choice to have a subnode tree is based on wanting to logical separate data. 4. Question 4 doesn't make sense, and how you want to combine information from the two containing data structures depends on your use case. 5. It really depends on your use case.

Comment: From what I gather, most of this depends on my use case.  The use case is specified at higher levels of the PST.  So, the NDB layer should expose all of the elements, and let higher levels figure out what to do with it? lol...

Comment: That isn't what I meant by use case. What I meant is what you are trying to do. It seems like you are trying to rewrite the PST SDK or write something similar to [PST-Parser](https://github.com/dancash/PST-Parser)

Comment: Been a pet project of mine for some time now to understand and comprehend the PST file format.  So, yes, rewriting the PST SDK.  Doing my best to not copy the PST SDK, but instead just get some understanding from it.  Not intending for this to be used in a production environment (unless I make it *really* good)

Comment: In that case, for 5. expose a stream for the data tree or a collection of datablocks with a stream interface per data block and either a traversal structure of subnodes containing data or a collection of subnodes and their associated data either as individual data blocks or streams, depending on the API you want to provide.

Comment: I don't know all of your assumptions. From the ones you have stated, the responses you have given are valid given your assumptions are correct, except where the answer specify otherwise.

Comment: Alright.  I think I'm good enough to stumble on through the rest of the specs.  Thanks a bunch for your assistance, I really appreciate it.  I'll award the bounty.